# Local MYSQL root password being reset every time I reboot machine

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, passwords, root

I have been having a very strange issue in the last few weeks where every time I reboot my machine the root password of my MYSQL installation gets reset and I have to manually force my way in to change it. As it is a local work environment the default password should be empty.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This only stated a few weeks ago as I said and may have coincided with the last Ubuntu upgrade but I Cannot be sure.

I have tried to access the MYSQL logs but these are empty on startup so doesn't provide me with any information.

Can anyone offer any assistance as to why this may be happening or any other way of troubleshooting it as I am at a loss as to where to go from here.

Edit: To add, when I reset the MYSQL root password after it has been changed I run the following commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & followed 
mysql -uroot

update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('') where user='root';
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you "manually force my way in to change it"? I see some possibilites where it can go wrong: you don't change the (correct) password. Or you start a different instance when you start your server manually: you may have a config file that points to a different data directory, that is used by the account you start the server manually with (e.g. root), but not when the system starts it (as e.g. user mysql, or with a specific given config file in the command line), so you change the password for a different server.

Comment: Sorry that comment was a bit vague of me. I stop the mysql service, then run sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables & followed by mysql -uroot to get into the mysql service... In there I run "update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('') where user='root';"

Comment: I have also added this to the main question.

Comment: What happens if you stop the server again and restart it without `--skip-grant-tables`? After reboot, what does `ps -eo cmd,args | grep mysql` tell you (especially the `--datadir` and `--defaults-extra-file` options) (or check your init-file)? Compare that to the server that is running now, `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = 'datadir'`. I still think you might have two data directories.

Comment: When I restart the service without skip grant tables it still works fine and does not change the root password

Comment: did you reach a solution? I have the same case here but He was using ubuntu mate with xamp earlier

Comment: I think your password was never reset your are only able to login when you type any password because mysqld --skip-grant-tables & is running in the background

Comment: I have a similar issue with my local development mysql install, it only happens every so often, every few months. I have a blank root password and I can no longer connect. I have to perform similar steps as in your question to reset the password to blank.